# sed command to fix filenames in a directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

I run a script which generated about 10k files in a directory. I just discovered that there is a bug in the script which causes some filenames to have a carriage return (presumably a '\n' character).

I want to run a sed command to remove the carriage return from the filenames.

Anyone knows which params to pass to sed to clean up the filenames in the manner described?

I am running Linux (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know how `sed` would do this, but this `python` script should do the trick:.

This isn't `sed`, but I find `python` a lot easier to use when doing things like these:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

files = os.listdir('.')

for file in files:
  os.rename(file, file.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', ''))
  print 'Processed ' + file.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '')
```

It strips any occurrences of both `\r` and `\n` from all of the filenames in a given directory.

To run it, save it somewhere, `cd` into your target directory (with the files to be processed), and run `python /path/to/the/file.py`.

Also, if you plan on doing more batch renaming, consider [Métamorphose](http://file-folder-ren.sourceforge.net/). It's a really nice and powerful GUI for this stuff. And, it's *free*!

Good luck!

---

Actually, try this: `cd` into the directory, type in `python`, and then just paste this in:

```
exec("import os\nfor file in os.listdir('.'):\n  os.rename(file, file.replace('\\r', '').replace('\\n', ''))\n  print 'Processed ' + file.replace('\\r', '').replace('\\n', '')")
```

It's a one-line version of the previous script, and you don't have to save it.

---

Version 2, with space replacement powers:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

for file in os.listdir('.'):
  os.rename(file, file.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '_')
  print 'Processed ' + file.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '')
```

And here's the one-liner:

```
exec("import os\nfor file in os.listdir('.'):\n  os.rename(file, file.replace('\\r', '').replace('\\n', '')replace(' ', '_'))\n  print 'Processed ' + file.replace('\\r', '').replace('\\n', '');")
```

Comment: @blender: thanks for the script. I run it ok, but the file names are still 'broken up' accross multiple lines. Which other character could be causing this?. Obviously \\r and \\n are not the culprits here :(

Comment: Are you sure that it's not just wrapping and spaces? For me, long filenames break up along the spaces. If you want, I could modify it to replace the spaces with underscores. Maybe that would help?

Comment: I've posted a space-replacement script too. Test that out, maybe that would work? No other characters besides `\n` and `\r` cause line breaks. It could be just your file manager...

Comment: Is this what you mean: http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/4416/screenshotvub.png? That's just Nautilus wrapping the name. There are no line breaks present, so the actual names have no newline characters.

Comment: @blender: No, they are definitely not spaces, and the wrapping is not being caused by nautilus. When I check the file properties, the filename contains some strange characters where the breaks occur. If I attempt to import the files (they are CSV files) into OpenOffice, the title of the Text Import looks like this: "this%0Dis%the%0Dfullname.csv"  Where the %0D is the character that is causing the filename to break accross multiple lines. HTH

Comment: 0D is the hex encoding for the carriage return character (aka \r) -- I suspect the problem is that the `strip` method only removes leading and trailing characters, not those in the middle of the filename.  To fix, replace `file.strip('\r\n')` in the first script with `file.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '')`.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for the catch ;) It should be functional now.

Comment: @Gordon/Blender: Thanks very much. Works like a charm now. All files fixed!

Answer (score 4):

If there are no spaces in your filenames, you can do:

```
for f in *$'\n'; do mv "$f" $f; done
```

It won't work if the newlines are embedded, but it will work for trailing newlines.

If you must use `sed`:

```
for f in *$'\n'; do mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed '/^$/d')"; done
```

Using the `rename` Perl script:

```
rename 's/\n//g' *$'\n'
```

or the util-linux-ng utility:

```
rename $'\n' '' *$'\n'
```

If the character is a return instead of a newline, change the `\n` or `^$` to `\r` in any places they appear above.

Comment: Back at zero ;) I'm not sure why people just randomly downvote. Probably newbies who just got the privilege wanted to get that new badge...

Comment: @Blender: Thanks. One for you is on its way.

Comment: It's like a form of currency now.

Comment: I vote this up, cause you're always providing quality answers. Even though I would like to see some `#!/bin/sh` compatible answers :)

Comment: @Blender: Maybe we can create an underground economy a la Second Life, etc. ;) By the way, I'll deny that I ever said that.

Comment: @Anders: The question is tagged `[bash]`. Also, each of my answers here should work just fine in the Bourne shell. If the version you're using doesn't support `$''`, just use a variable. `nl=$(printf '\n'); nl=${nl%.}; for f in *"$nl"`. I will try to include more `sh` versions.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you aren't getting any pure-`sed` answers is that fundamentally `sed` edits file contents, not file names; thus the answers that use sed all do something like echo the filename into a pipe (pseudo file), edit that with `sed`, then use `mv` to turn that back into a filename.

Since `sed` is out, here's a pure-bash version to add to the Perl, Python, etc scripts you have so far:

```
killpattern=$'[\r\n]' # remove both carriage returns and linefeeds
for f in *; do
    if [[ "$f" == *$killpattern* ]]; then
        mv "$f" "${f//$killpattern/}"
    fi
done
```

...but since `${var//pattern/replacement}` isn't available in plain `sh` (along with `[[...]]`), here's a version using `sh`-only syntax, and `tr` to do the character replacement:

```
for f in *; do
    new="$(printf %s "$f" | tr -d "\r\n")"
    if [ "$f" != "$new" ]; then
        mv "$f" "$new"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: If you really want it with `sed`, take a look at this:

- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/merge-lines-in-a-file-using-sed-191121/

Something along these lines should work similar to the `perl` below:

```
for i in *; do echo mv "$i" `echo "$i"|sed ':a;N;s/\n//;ta'`; done
```

With perl, try something along these lines:

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" `echo "$i"|perl -pe 's/\n//g'`; done
```

This will rename all files in the current folder by removing all newline characters from them. If you need to go recursive, you can use `find` instead - be aware of the escaping in that case, though.

Comment: Nobody can figure out how to do it with `sed` ;)

Comment: I edited to add the `sed` solution - when I first answered I used `perl` as `sed` is not a tool suited for multi-line editing (as you can see from the line - perl one is much simpler to follow).

Comment: Meh, I still prefer Python over `sed` any day. It's so much easier to work with.

Comment: @Blender: The tough part with `sed` is that it sees the newlines as starting a completely new input line. My `sed` version simply deletes empty lines from the input.

Answer (score 0):

In fact there is a way to use sed:

```
carr='\n'                                        # specify carriage return
files=( $(ls -f) )                               # array of files in current dir
for i in ${files[@]}
do 
    if [[ -n $(echo "$i" | grep $carr) ]]        # filenames with carriage return
    then
        mv "$i" "$(echo "$i" | sed 's/\\n//g')"  # move!
    fi
done
```

This actually works.