# BASH - Recursively rename files containing invalid/non-printing characters

Tags: bash, sed, filenames, rename

I manually renamed a lot of files (e-books) based on the title from within the PDF file that contains the book. I did this by manually copying the multi-line text within my PDF reader, then renaming the file within Nautilus. I wanted to add these all to an SVN repo, but the add command failed due to the file name itself for multiple PDFs containing the `0x0A` (newline) character. My locale is set to UTF8 in my `.bashrc` file, and it seems that Ubuntu's Nautilus File Explorer utility allows me to paste non-printing characters into the file name (**is it possible to disable this?**).

Anyhow, I now have a large directory containing subdirectories, PDFs, PDFs within the subdirectories, etc. Is there a way to recursively traverse the directory structure and remove any non-printing characters (ie: newlines) from the file names?

I tried the following to loop through the files (**which contain spaces in their names**):

```
#!/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for f in *
do
  echo "Renaming $f"
  mv ${f} $(echo ${f} | sed 's/\n//g')
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

However, files with newlines in their file name are printed on two separate lines, as if they are separate entries. I've found a possible solution on SO ([sed command to fix filenames in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417588/sed-command-to-fix-filenames-in-a-directory)), but it only works if all the files are in the same directory, rather than the big subdirectory structure I currently have.

Thank you.

Comment: Depending on the file names, it might make more sense to replace every newline with a space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use IFS. Just enclose your arguments around `""` to prevent word splitting:

```
mv "${f}" "$(echo "${f}" | sed 's/\n//g')"
```

Also, you can just use special parameter expansion to remove newlines:

```
mv "${f}" "${f//$'\n'}"
```

See [Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) and [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Note: Only open variables are affected by IFS. Immediate glob patterns like `*` when they expand do not split.

To enable recursion with globs, enable `globstar`: `shopt -s globstar`. Then you can do

```
for f in /path/to/dir/**; do
    [[ ! -d $f ]] && mv "$f" "${f//$'\n'}"  ## Test lets it process files only.
done
```

Using `find`:

```
find -type f '/path/to/dir' -print0 | while IFS= read -rd '' f; do
    mv "$f" "${f//$'\n'}"
done
```

Same as using process substitution:

```
while IFS= read -rd ''; do
    mv "$f" "${f//$'\n'}"
done < <(exec find -type f '/path/to/dir' -print0)
```

With `IFS=`, `read` disables word splitting from input. `-r` disables interpreting backslash quotes and `-d ''` sets delimiter to `0x00`. It works with `find` which sets `0x00` as the output delimiter instead of newline (`0x0A`) with `-print0`.

It may also be possible to use character sets:

```
[:alpha:]   Alphabetic characters.
[:blank:]   Space and TAB characters.
[:cntrl:]   Control characters.
[:digit:]   Numeric characters.
[:graph:]   Characters that are both printable and visible.
[:lower:]   Lowercase alphabetic characters.
[:print:]   Printable characters (characters that are not control characters).
[:punct:]   Punctuation characters (characters that are not letters, digits,
[:space:]   Space characters (such as space, TAB, and formfeed, to name a few).
[:upper:]   Uppercase alphabetic characters.
[:xdigit:]  Characters that are hexadecimal digits.
```

You probably wanted:

```
mv "$f" "${f//[[:cntrl:]]}"
```

Or

```
mv "$f" "${f//[^[:print:]]}"  ## Does not only include control chars but probably some if not all extended chars as well.
```

You can join them too:

```
mv "$f" "${f//[[:cntrl:]|!@#$%^&*()]}"
```

Of course test them first before doing the actual run:

```
echo mv "$f" "${f//[[:cntrl:]|!@#$%^&*()]}"
```

Comment: +1 but maybe also show how to use `find` to do this across a tree of directories.

Comment: Awesome. Also, thanks for including the `find`-based example.